# Not all devices connect to AP D-LINK DAP-1610

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have AP D-LINK DAP-1610. I had a problem connecting it to LINKSYS WAG120N while MAC filtering was enabled on LINKSYS. Finally I did it, turned out there was a difference between MAC on the sticker on bottom of AP. Also, some other MAC addresses appeared on router DHCP list (they are not mentioned on AP configuration list).

I added 5 MAC addresses related with AP to router whitelist. I enabled filtering permitting to connect only those on list.

Now I added MAC address of a laptop with Windows 7 (not sure if this has any importance) and MAC of two mobile phones with Android Pie. Laptop connected, phones did not. They try to get IP address and that's all.

I disabled MAC filtering and phones connected. After enabling it again they lost connection.

I configured AP manually (not using Protected Setup button).

Lets say router network is named 'network'. AP network is called 'network-EXT'.

Networks have different password.

Someone adviced me to disable MAC Randomization on Android Pie, but I don't have this option on phone. Also, phone already connected to that network.

What to do to connect mobile phones to AP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many phones randomise their MAC address until a secure connection is established.

From Source:Android - [Privacy: MAC Randomization](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization)
iMore - [What's really happening with iOS 8 MAC address randomization?](https://www.imore.com/closer-look-ios-8s-mac-randomization)

Additionally, using MAC address filtering is a false sense of security -
HowToGeek - [Why You Shouldn’t Use MAC Address Filtering On Your Wi-Fi Router](https://www.howtogeek.com/204458/why-you-shouldn%E2%80%99t-use-mac-address-filtering-on-your-wi-fi-router/)
& Security SE - [Does MAC address filtering provide security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121025/does-mac-address-filtering-provide-security)